# Read CSV from within Zip File

Tags: python, csv, zip

I have a directory of zip files (approximately 10,000 small files), within each is a CSV file I am trying to read and split into a number of different CSV files.

I managed to write the code to split the CSV files from a directory of CSVs, shown below, that reads the first atttribute of the CSV, and depending what it is write it to the relevent CSV.

```
import csv
import os
import sys
import re
import glob

reader = csv.reader(open("C:/Projects/test.csv", "rb"), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
write10 = csv.writer(open('ouput10.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
write15 = csv.writer(open('ouput15.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)


headings10=["RECORD_IDENTIFIER","CUSTODIAN_NAME","LOCAL_CUSTODIAN_NAME","PROCESS_DATE","VOLUME_NUMBER","ENTRY_DATE","TIME_STAMP","VERSION","FILE_TYPE"]
write10.writerow(headings10)

headings15=["RECORD_IDENTIFIER","CHANGE_TYPE","PRO_ORDER","USRN","STREET_DESCRIPTION","LOCALITY_NAME","TOWN_NAME","ADMINSTRATIVE_AREA","LANGUAGE"]
write15.writerow(headings15)


for row in reader:
    type = row[0]
    if "10" in type:        
        write10.writerow(row)
    elif "15" in type:
        write15.writerow(row)
```

So I am now trying to read the Zip files rather than wasting time extracting them first.

This is what I have so far after following as many tutorials as I have found

```
import glob
import os
import csv
import zipfile
import StringIO

for name in glob.glob('C:/Projects/abase/*.zip'):
    base = os.path.basename(name)
    filename = os.path.splitext(base)[0]


datadirectory = 'C:/Projects/abase/'
dataFile = filename
archive = '.'.join([dataFile, 'zip'])
fullpath = ''.join([datadirectory, archive])
csv = '.'.join([dataFile, 'csv'])


filehandle = open(fullpath, 'rb')
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filehandle)
data = StringIO.StringIO(zfile.read(csv))
reader = csv.reader(data)

for row in reader:
    print row
```

However and error gets thrown

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reader'

Hopefully someone can show me how to change my CSV reading code that works to read the Zip file.

Much appreciated

Tim

Comment: Maybe it is how you pasted the code, but hardly anything is in your for name loop.  What line is the error referring to?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simple fix. You're overriding the `csv` module with your local `csv` variable. Just change the name of that variable:

```
import glob
import os
import csv
import zipfile
import StringIO

for name in glob.glob('C:/Projects/abase/*.zip'):
    base = os.path.basename(name)
    filename = os.path.splitext(base)[0]


    datadirectory = 'C:/Projects/abase/'
    dataFile = filename
    archive = '.'.join([dataFile, 'zip'])
    fullpath = ''.join([datadirectory, archive])
    csv_file = '.'.join([dataFile, 'csv']) #all fixed


    filehandle = open(fullpath, 'rb')
    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filehandle)
    data = StringIO.StringIO(zfile.read(csv_file)) #don't forget this line!
    reader = csv.reader(data)

    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Comment: However, it does not seem to loop through the zip files?

Comment: @user1218419: check your indentation.  As Scott Hunter noted, most of your code is below, and therefore outside of, your `for name in glob.glob('c:etc'):` loop.

Comment: worked like a dream, ran through the 7000 files in 1hr 40 mins compared to using gawk which did it in 28hrs!!!

Comment: `StringIO` is in the `io` package in Python 3.